# Firebase always returning all the rows

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am querying on firebase to fetch data from last point which was previously fetched but it is always giving all the rows.

Code:

```
Query query = null;
        query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.orderByKey();
        String lastKey = getLastKey();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastKey)) {
            query.startAt(lastKey);
        }
```

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("NODE_NAME").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // you can get last node values..
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Handle possible errors.
    }
});
```

// where NODE_NAME is the root of all these child keys.

Comment: means you want to fetch data from last point ,which was fetch by you last time.

Comment: I want to fetch data from last key i fetched