# Do not show the same values in a Firebase on each ngfor Loop - Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

In general if you have an ngFor loop that grabs from firebase, which has a limitTo 10 at a time, how do you pull the next 10 values and not start at the first value when calling the firebase list.

How do i grab the next 10 records from my for loop, from the firebase database.

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
console.log('Begin async operation');
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.Aproducts.push( this.Aproducts[i] );
    //console.log(this.Aproducts.pop());
  }

  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  infiniteScroll.complete();
}, 100);
```

}

Comment: I found this: but it doesn't help my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731060/firebase-always-returning-all-the-rows?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: How can i take my for loop and push the key to firebase to grab only the next 10 records everytime? doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.Aproducts.push( this.Aproducts[i] );
        //console.log(this.Aproducts.pop());
      }

      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 100);
  }

Answer (score 0):

In general - you can do this by using the functionality of firebase queries. 
All firebase queries must start with an orderBy function, for example the orderByPriority (firebase default priority). Then you can specify a limitTofirst and startAt like this:

```
const queryObservable = af.database.list('/items', {
  query: {
    orderByPriority: true,
    limitToFirst: 10,
    startAt: key,
  }
});
```

Read more about the query options [in the github documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md).